# Make waterline accept async custom validation

Tags: node.js, validation, asynchronous, waterline

How do I use async custom validation in waterline ?

I tried :

```
module.export = {
  types: {
    album : function(albumId) {
      Album.findOne(albumId)
      .then(function(album) {
        console.log(album !== undefined); // true
        return album != undefined;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return false;
      });
      // if I return true there, it works
    },
  }
  attributes: {
    album: {
      model: 'album',
      album: true
    }
  }
}
```

But it seems that validation is rejected because validation function returns before promise is successed. I Also tried returning the promise but it doesn't work :P